# How to execute a callback on JqueryUI dialog when the dialog is closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am using JueryUI dialog to display an alert message.
The issue that is occuring for me is that callback is immediately being executed.  I would expect the callback only to be executed once the dialog box is closed.

Is there a proper way to ensure the callback doesnt execute until the dialog is closed?

```
 myAlert = function (title, msg, callback) {
        var alertElement = $('#alertElement ');
            alertElement .dialog({
                modal: false,
                resizable: false,
                width: 500,
                buttons: {
                    OK: function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                },
                open: function (event, ui) {
                    $(this).parent().find('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').hide(); 
                    $(this).parent().find('.ui-dialog-buttonpane button:first').focus();
                },
                close: function () {
                    if (typeof callback == "function")
                    { callback(); }
                }
            });
        }
    };
```

This is my call...

```
var urlString = "some url string";
function printWindow(urlString) {            
    window.open(urlString, 'Print', "toolbar=no,menubar=no,status=no");
};

myAlert("Warning", "This is a warning.", printWindow(url));
```

Comment: You need to wrap `printWindow(url)` in a function: `function() { printWindow(url); }`.  Sure this must be a duplicate question though, but can't find anything...

Comment: That resolved it, but now causes another issue with the url parameter.  If it's changed client side that value never gets updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

callback is immediately being executed because you are invoking it with `()`, so the return value of `printWindow` method will be passed to `myAlert`.

To pass `printWindow` to be called later with the `url` as an argument you can use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) method:

```
myAlert("Warning", "This is a warning.", printWindow.bind(null,url));
```

return value of the bind method is a new `printWindow` function whose first parameter will be the second argument (`url`) passed to bind.

Comment: I did try the bind suggestion, however my printWindow is not being invoked on the callback.

Comment: The bind worked.  I didn't realize at first that I had it wrapped in a function.
After tweaking my code I was able to get my issue resolved without using a global variable. Thanks!